# Comparing an std::array to a traditional array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am trying to perform a comparison of elements in:

```
std::vector<std::array<uint8_t, 6> > _targets =
{
  { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x11 }
  { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x22 }
};
```

to a traditional array:

```
 uint8_t _traditional[6] =  { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x33 }
```

as:

```
  for (auto target : _targets) 
  {

     if (! memcmp(target, _traditional, 6)) {
        known = 1;
     } 
  }
```

and am receiving a data conversion error:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::array<unsigned char, 6u>' to 'const void*' for argument '1' to 'int memcmp(const 
void*, const void*, size_t)
```

What is the propert byte wise comparison operation I can perform to accomplish equality evaluation?

Comment: why not make `_traditional` also a `std::array` and use `==`?

Comment: @Cheers is there a way to temporarily cast it? its part of a large 3rd party library I leveraging

Comment: How about [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)?

Comment: Careful with those leading underscores. Sometimes they mean something special. [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `data()` member of `array` to get a pointer to the contained array:

```
if (! memcmp(target.data(), _traditional, 6))
```

The alternative of using `&target[0]` will work in this case (where you're storing a `uint8_t`) but won't work if you store a class that overloads the unary `&` (address) operator.  But you could use `std::addressof(target[0])` which will work even in the presence of an overloaded address operator.

Comment: One of those cases where it should work unless the implementer of `std::array` was insane or solving a very interesting problem`

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, but could you replace `target.data()` with `&target[0]` ?

Comment: In addition to `target.data()` only `&target[0]` is guaranteed to work. afaik (possibly `&target` too but not certain tbh).

Comment: @galik If the type stored has overridden `&` then `&target[0]` may differ from `target.data()`, otherwise it won't differ.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Well the question is asking about `uint8_t`, otherwise `memcmp` would be dicing it.